Is there an option in GPO to disable "Fallback to unauthorized network" checkbox in the settings of the wired network adapter?
I,m trying to disable "Fallback to unauthorized network" checkbox in the settings of the wired network adapter, but I could not find this setting in the Group Policy.
Is there an option in GPO to disable "Fallback to unauthorized network" checkbox in the settings of the wired network adapter?
.
